# Exactly once in confluent_kafka v0.11.2 for Python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, confluent-platform

How do I enable.idempotency or change the processing.guarantee to exactly_once in python3.6 for confluent kafka v0.11.4. A lot of documentation from confluent kafka only talks about Scala and Java.
I tried doing something like this:

```
p = Producer({
        'bootstrap.servers':'localhost:9092',
        'processing.guarantee' : 'exactly_once'
    })
```

But I got this exception:

```
cimpl.KafkaException: KafkaError{code=_INVALID_ARG,val=-186,str="No such 
configuration property: "processing.guarantee""}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know how this works specifically for Python, but you can only get exactly once delivery with Kafka if you're using Kafka Streams (leverating the transactions api). If you're not using the Kafka Streams library, exactly once is not available (or possible).

Learn more about how this works here: confluent.io/blog/enabling-exactly-kafka-streams

Comment: Except Kafka Streams isn't available as a Python library. And Kafka Streams isn't the **only** way. Flink and Spark can do it